# Content Field is invalid when adding a text field to prestashop via CMS.

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i am trying to add a text field using prestashop CMS option, i can easily save drop downs that i have created, but when i try to save the text field it gives me this error

`The content field is invalid.`.
Following is my HTML Block.

```
<h1>Sell your item</h1>
<p>Select Category:</p>
<select class="selectBox selectBox-dropdown selectProductSort" name="catgeory_dropdown">
    <option value="">-- Select Category</option>
    <option value="category1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="category2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="category3">category 3</option>
</select>
<p>
    <input id="item_name" class="search_query ac_input" autocomplete="off" name="item_name" type="text" /></p>
<p>Select Category:</p>
<select class="selectBox selectBox-dropdown selectProductSort" name="catgeory_dropdown">
    <option value="">-- Select Category</option>
    <option value="category1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="category2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="category3">category 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me the same error message when I tried to put `input` fields in contents.